# Drop pending Mnesia transactions

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I have a Mnesia database and when I restart my application, I get an error (badarg) in the pending transactions. I think an invalid value was about to be inserted.
How can I inspect the pending transactions to look up what the bad value is and how can I drop that value from the pending transactions without deleting the whole database.

**Update:**

The crash report is the following:

```
{badarg, [{ets, insert, [{image_db...}, {image_db...}...]
```

Where `image_db` is my struct which gets inserted into the database. Unforunately the list of items to get inserted is so long, that I don't see the corrupt value.

The command `mnesia:info()` shows me 1 aborted transaction on startup.

**Update 2:**

How can I read the binary log files in the mnesia db directory?

**Update 3:**

It's a local single-node Mnesia Table. I initialize it like this:

```
mnesia:stop(),
catch(mnesia:create_schema([node()])),
mnesia:start(),
timer:sleep(1000), % vital but ugly as hell
mnesia:create_table(?DBNAME, [{disc_copies, [node()]}, {type, ordered_set},
                              {attributes, record_info(fields, image_db)}]),
mnesia:wait_for_tables(?DBNAME, 1000),
```

where the `image_db` record looks like this:

```
-type now_time() :: {integer(), integer(), integer() }.

-record(image_db, {time :: now_time(),
                   path :: string(),
                   size :: integer() }).
```

The Problem appears from time to time, I think after an invalid record gets inserted into the db. I added a record-validation function now to avoid this, but the question still remains, how to recover the database by dropping the invalid values in the stored transactions?

Comment: please show the error you are getting exactly

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering if your mnesia is a multi-node environment and, if so, are you waiting for the tables to come on-line (so to speak) and get synchronized before beginning to insert them? Can you give us more info about your configuration. Also, does this happen all the time or only occasionally?